# Can't install Bluecloth 2.2.0 gem in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, windows-7-x64, ruby-2.0

When Running `bundle install` i am getting below error.

Note: I also tried `gem install bluecloth --platform=ruby` but same problem.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
checking for srand()... yes
checking for random()... no
checking for rand()... yes
checking for bzero() in string.h,strings.h... no
checking for strcasecmp()... yes
checking for strncasecmp()... yes
checking for mkdio.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating bluecloth_ext-i386-mingw32.def
compiling bluecloth.c
In file included from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-     mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:59:0,
             from c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/winsock2.h:23,
             from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:40,
             from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153,
             from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
             from c:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
             from bluecloth.h:14,
             from bluecloth.c:25:
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:113:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:113:23: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/windef.h:114:24: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
c:\devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-  mingw32/include/windef.h:115:23: error: duplicate 'unsigned'
make: *** [bluecloth.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0    for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bluecloth-2.2.0/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bluecloth (2.2.0), and Bundler cannot
```

continue.

Make sure that `gem install bluecloth -v '2.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Process finished with exit code 5

....................................................................

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.0.0"

## Bundle rails:
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
 gem 'pg'
gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem "activemerchant", '~> 1.29.3'#, :lib => 'active_merchant'
gem "american_date"

# Use https if you are pushing to HEROKU
##  NOTE: run the test before upgrading to the tagged version. It has had several deprecation warnings.
gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic', ref: 'e4b2990d6282f3f7b50249b4f639631aef68b939'
#gem 'authlogic',          "~> 3.3.0"

gem "asset_sync"
gem 'awesome_nested_set', '~> 3.0.0.rc.1'

gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'bluecloth',      '~> 2.2.0'
gem 'cancan',         '~> 1.6.8'
gem 'chronic'
# Use https if you are pushing to HEROKU
gem 'compass-rails', git: 'https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git'
#gem 'compass-rails',  git: 'git://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git'


gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem "friendly_id",    '~> 5.0.1'#, :git => "git@github.com:FriendlyId/friendly_id.git", :branch => 'rails4'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'json',           '~> 1.8.0'

#gem "nifty-generators", :git => 'git://github.com/drhenner/nifty-generators.git'
gem 'nokogiri',     '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'paperclip',    '~> 3.0'
gem 'prawn',        '~> 0.12.0'

gem "rails3-generators", "~> 1.0.0"
#git: "https://github.com/neocoin/rails3-generators.git"
gem "rails_config"
gem 'rmagick',    :require => 'RMagick'

gem 'rake', '~> 10.1'

# gem 'resque', require: 'resque/server'

gem 'state_machine', '~> 1.2.0'
#gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.0.0'
#gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.4'
gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.3.2'

group :production do
  #gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.12'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  #gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'railroady'
  #gem 'awesome_print'
  #gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
  gem "autotest-rails-pure"
  gem "better_errors", '~> 0.9.0'
  gem "binding_of_caller", '~> 0.7.2'
  gem 'debugger'#, '~> 1.6.1'
  gem "rails-erd"

  # YARD AND REDCLOTH are for generating yardocs
  gem 'yard'
  gem 'RedCloth'
end
group :test, :development do
  gem 'capybara', "~> 1.1"#, :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner', "~> 1.2"
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl', "~> 3.3.0"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 3.3.0"
  gem 'mocha', '~> 0.13.3', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails-mocha'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.12.2'

  gem 'email_spec'
  gem "faker"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It duplicate:
[Bluecloth v2.0.10 with windows 7 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932221/bluecloth-v2-0-10-with-windows-7-not-working)

I tried It is working fine:

If you need 2.2.0 (the latest version), here's how I got it to work:

Install DevKit

Run the command below to install bluecloth:

gem install bluecloth

this will fail miserably when building "native extensions", but will successfully install the gem's source code.

Patch bluecloth.h file (for me, this is found in: D:\ruby\Ruby-1.9.3-p125\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0\ext), with the patch from here: https://gist.github.com/1539611

Go to bluecloth's gem installation folder. For me, this looks like below:

D:\ruby\Ruby-1.9.3-p125\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0

Run the following command:

rake gem

It may prompt you to install some other gems, follow accordingly. When it's done, you should see a bluecloth-2.2.0.gem created. For me, it is found here:

D:\ruby\Ruby-1.9.3-p125\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bluecloth-2.2.0\pkg\bluecloth-2.2.0.gem

Go to bluecloth-2.2.0.gem location, and run the following command:

gem install bluecloth-2.2.0.gem --platform=ruby